# Preparing NodeJS DB content for use in Mustache

Tags: json, node.js, underscore.js

I have a library of FAQs that are split up into tabs on the front end, we have since built a NodeJS app that handles them so we can have a database of FAQs instead of hardcoded HTML.

I have a NodeJS model generating a JSON file that is filtering the questions by their tab association using the following:

```
res = _.groupBy(res, 'tab_title');
```

Which is outputting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEsI1.png).

However, below is the structure of the original JSON file that the Mustache tags in the template are expecting it to look like:

```
{
"tabs": [
    {
        "title": "Tab title",
        "id": 1,
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Question here",
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "Answer here"
            },
            {
                "question": "Question two",
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "Answer here"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Another title",
        "id": 2,
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Question here",
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "Answer here"
            },
            {
                "question": "Question two",
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "Answer here"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is so the front end tags can just loop over the tabs, then loop over the questions within the tabs so the front end is relatively automated.

I have tried to use the `_.map` function to output all the appropriate information in this structure but I'm really struggling. Can anyone point my in a direction that could help?

I hope this is enough information, but if not, I can supply more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So we start by generating the groups like you did.

```
_.groupBy(myArray, 'tab_title');
```

However, that doesn't quite solve our issue here, the object still wont match the intended structure. It'll look like :

```
{
    "tab_title1" : [{...}, {...}],
    "tab_title2" : [{...}, {...}]
}
```

So we could use the map function to process this further :

```
_.map(groupObject, (lstFaqs, tab_title) => {
    let first = _.first(lstFaqs),
        tab_object = { 
            title: first.tab_title, 
            id: first.tab_id, 
            questions: _.map(lstFaqs, (faqItem) => {
               id: faqItem.faq_id,
               question : faqItem.faq_question,
               answer : faqItem.faq_answer
            }) 
        }

    return tab_object;
})
```

We'll end up with an array of tab_object. So to finalize the formatting :

```
let result = { "tabs" : array_of_tab_object }
```

I hope this help!